# Does Firebase migration require any source code modification?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Recently I have migrated one of my `iOS` apps from `Fabric` to `Firebase` using migration link shown in Fabric dashboard. Crashes are appearing fine in the Firebase console. Does that migration require any source code modification for next release to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Here's what the Firebase doc has to say:

> **What happened when you migrated?**
>
> For the apps that you linked, your Crashlytics data now appears in the Firebase Crashlytics
>   dashboard (in the Firebase console). The linking process does not
>   involve any changes to the Crashlytics SDK or your Fabric API key.
>
> Note that in the coming months, we'll release Firebase-specific
>   Crashlytics SDKs for iOS and for Android, as well as offer further
>   upgrade instructions. So, for now, if you migrated an iOS and Android
>   app:
>
> *Do not change how you use the Crashlytics SDK because the iOS and
>   Android SDKs haven't changed.*
>
> *Do not change or remove your Fabric API key.*

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking

And here's what Firebase Crashlytic dashboard migration assistance looks like:

[image]